# Check if a file exist in javascript within wkwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cors, wkwebview

I'm building an hybrid app and I've been trying to test if a local image exists in local before using it, but I'm stuck on iOS with the wkwebview because I got CORS errors.

```
var loadImage = function(urlImage) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', urlImage, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(false);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        deferred.resolve(false);
    };
    xhr.send();
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I'm getting the following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "". Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

I would prefer not using a plugin to bypass this error,is there a way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a userContentController to your WKWebView and then post a message from your Javascript code to have it handle the request in the app native environment.

Add this in viewDidLoad

```
yourWebView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")
```

and then

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "callbackHandler" {
        let content = message.body as! String
...
```

So you can communicate with the app using

```
webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage('a message');
```